# Curacao visa on arrival

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival, caribbean, aruba

Can an Indian passport holder, going from Delhi to Curacao to Panama, not having a USA or Canada or EU visa, get a visa to enter Curacao on arrival?

Comment: is it a single booking and a through ticket? or will you have to clear immigration and check your bag in again?

Comment: ticket will be Panama - Curacao - Jamaica by Copa Air

Answer (score 1):

You wont need a visa to transit Curacao. It seems you meet the requirements below.

> You are transiting through an airport in one of the Caribbean parts of
> the Kingdom, hold an onward ticket and meet the following
> requirements:
>
> Aruba:    Transit between 7:00 and 23:00 uur
>
> St Maarten: same calendar day
>
> Bonaire, **Curaçao**, St Eustatius and Saba:  Transit within 48 hours

As long as your transit is within 48 hours and have an onwards ticket you're fine without a visa.

If you're transit is longer you'll need to apply for a [short stay visa](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/caribbean-visas/applying-for-a-short-stay-caribbean-visa)

More information can be found on the [Kingdom of the Netherlands travel website](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/caribbean-visas/do-i-need-a-visa-for-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom).